# Facebook style friends sidebar bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

```
<div class="sidebar-nav-fixed">
   <div class="row">
      <div>
         <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
         <img src="images/geeks-thumbnail.jpeg">
         </a>
      </div>
      <div>
         <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
         <img src="images/geeks-thumbnail.jpeg">
         </a>
      </div>
      <div>
         <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
         <img src="images/geeks-thumbnail.jpeg">
         </a>
      </div>
      <div>
         <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
         <img src="images/geeks-thumbnail.jpeg">
         </a>
      </div>
      <div>
         <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
         <img src="images/geeks-thumbnail.jpeg">
         </a>
      </div>
      <div>
         <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
         <img src="images/geeks-thumbnail.jpeg">
         </a>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I want to display these profile thumbnails 3 in each row inside sidebar. I am using thumbnail class in it but these all are coming 1 image on each line.

Kindly help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of items in a `row` is decided by the `col-` class ([Grid system docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic))

For three items per row you would use `col-**-4`:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="sidebar-nav-fixed">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4">
         <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
         <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
         </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
         <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
         <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
         </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
         <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
         <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
         </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
         <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
         <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
         </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
         <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
         <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
         </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
         <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
         <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
         </a>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to fix that like this

```
<div class="sidebar-nav-fixed">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
     <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
     <img src="images/geeks-thumbnail.jpeg">
     </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
     <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
     <img src="images/geeks-thumbnail.jpeg">
     </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
     <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
     <img src="images/geeks-thumbnail.jpeg">
     </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
     <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
     <img src="images/geeks-thumbnail.jpeg">
     </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
     <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
     <img src="images/geeks-thumbnail.jpeg">
     </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
     <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
     <img src="images/geeks-thumbnail.jpeg">
     </a>
  </div>
```